# Element not found on Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

As on the image i have record some steps using Selenium IDE.
st i click on the `Add Time Entry Link`. And it will open a pop up.
In side the pop up there are some fields to add values.
But when i run the selenium test case using the IDE it says

> Element not found

So how to resolve this issue.I have manually[image] add `Pause` but no luck.

And this is how the HTML code looks like[image]

Comment: Im confused, are you saying adding Pause DOES or DOES NOT fix the issue?

Comment: Please put the html behind the object you are attempting to connect with.

Comment: HTML Code added as an image

Comment: I don't see a <select> tag in your html. The select option in Selenium IDE is to select an option in a select tag. Is the relevant html code missing from the screenprint or is what you think is a select list actually a group of divs?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the first select for `EmployeeComboBox` works but it then gets stuck on `Work_DateTextBox` I would try adding another wait between them.

I would also recommend not using the recorder at all.  Better to step through the form or workflow manually creating steps one by one using good practices for identifying elements uniquely and using waits and switch window appropriately.  The seleniumIDE is a powerful tool if you write the steps and expectations carefully.